# How to force/request vlc to buffer a video completely?

Tags: networking, mount, vlc, nfs

I'm watching videos on network mounts of a home server (`cifs` or `nfs` - that shouldn't matter) and experience the videos to cut during reboots during maintenance because the network mounts are not served for the time of the reboot. I'd like avoid those cuts by forcing `vlc` to buffer the complete video or `n` minutes (don't care about the memory consumption). I naively assume that `vlc` will continue buffering as soon as the network mount becomes available again if only `n` minutes are buffered.

I'm using `vlc` 2.2.0-0-g1349ef2 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open vlc, go to Tools > Preferences, from bottom left tick Show Settings > All, then in the left tree go to Input/Codecs, then on the right scroll down to Advanced and change File caching (ms). Save.

Comment: Setting all ms values to `100000` doesn't cause a file on an `cifs` to be cached, e.g. if I start the playback of a 20 minute video file and leave it one minute to retrieve the file (copying into `/tmp/` takes 3 seconds), then cut the internet connection  and seek a position in the middle `vlc` displays a black screen. If I reestablish the connection it resumes playback immediately.